# Google app engine instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I have one python instance running in Google app engine (billing enabled). Now if my users increase and number of requests increase, then -

Google app engine automatically scales and handles all the requests or should I have to do anything like creating more frontend instances (to accommodate the increase in user traffic)?

Answer (score 2):

App Engine will automatically scale the instances to accomodate for increased traffic.

You can change how instances are scaled up with the settings in the App Engine dashboard.  Go to Application Settings > Performance and you can change a couple of settings to alter how instances are spun up.  The settings you want to look at are:

- **Frontend Instance Class:** How beefy your instances are.
- **Idle Instances:** The minimum number of instances that will be waiting for traffic.
- **Pending Latency:** How much latency will trigger spinning up a new instance.

Comment: Does these performance options available for GAE Flex?

Answer (score 0):

App engine automatically scales base on your traffic, the only limit is your daily budget.

Answer (score -1):

You should read more about [warmup request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Warmup_requests) and set application configuration but if it heavy traffic if not do care just pay more. You should think also about some sharding if it required.